# Dynamic Box colour change onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m trying to change color using the onclick event. Like on first click RED color ,then on next click Green color,then on another click again backt o RED color. I have completed the click concept but did not understand how to set color concept using JS. **Any simple solution?**

```
<head>
    <script>
        function getValue() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myHeader");
            alert(x.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">Click me!</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: in simple word i want to change color of "click me " on every click the "click me " color change its may be three color or more and repeated....@Klaster_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small example using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/4vq2psLh/)

```
function display() {
  var colours = new Array();
  colours[0] = "red";
  colours[1] = "blue";
  colours[2] = "green";
  colours[3] = "lime";
  colours[4] = "teal";

  var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length);
  document.getElementById("quotation").style.color = colours[b];
}
```

And also you can use colours as follows,

```
var colours = ["#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#333399",...];
```

Comment: if i have an div with height and width with border how  do same colour change in it onclick?